# How to add shipping address in paypal express checkout

Tags: paypal

I am using following code for Paypal express checkout,

```
<form id="paypal-form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="name@email.com">
                    
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                <div><input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1"></div>
                <div><input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Tomato"></div>
                <div><input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="SKU Tomato"></div>
                <div><input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="700.70"></div>
                <div><input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="0.00"></div>
                <span class="waves-input-wrapper waves-effect waves-light"><input type="submit" id="paypal-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm px-3 rounded-pill" value="Pay with PayPal"></span>
</form>
```

1. I need to add shipping address to this. Is it possible?
2. Also what is the live production url for `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`.
3. Is there any way to add another email address to get extra notification email?

Edit: Solution from Preston PHX - [This](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#link-autofillpaypalcheckoutpagevariables) link provide available variables. I can use `address_override`. Live url is `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`. Also It seems to be not possible to add additional emails to get notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an express checkout, that is the old [HTML payments standard](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#link-autofillpaypalcheckoutpagevariables).

You should use [the current PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/). The best flow obtains the address from PayPal after the user signs in, so they don't have to enter it manually if it's saved in their account. This allows for faster checkouts. You can adjust the total based on the address before capturing. It's also possible to offer different shipping options based on the address chosen.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I will be ok with old HTML method for now. Can you please add solution for that in your answer.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#link-autofillpaypalcheckoutpagevariables